# How to upload images to firebase storage in meantime user filling form but save it only when user accept form

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

i am creating mobile app using react native expo managed workflow. I want to achieve that when user is adding new car, it opens camera roll, user choose few photos and accept. Now user is filling form and in meantime photos are uploading, but i wan't to pause it when it is for example 99% and finish it in database when user accept form. Bacause user can change mind in meantime and choose new photos or close form, i don't want to store photos in this situation in my firebase storage.

```html
import { firebase } from "../src/firebase/config";
import resizePhoto from "./resizePhoto";

let carsRef;
let carImagesRef;

const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

const uploadImage = async (blobImage) => {
  var random = Math.random();
  var uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/" + random).put(blobImage);

  const imageUrl = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    uploadTask.on(
      firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
      function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.state);
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
            console.log("Upload is paused");
            break;
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
            console.log("Upload is running");
            break;
        }
      },
      function (error) {
        // A full list of error codes is available at
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
        switch (error.code) {
          case "storage/unauthorized":
            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
            break;

          case "storage/canceled":
            // User canceled the upload
            break;

          case "storage/unknown":
            // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
            break;
        }
      },
      function () {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function (downloadURL) {
          resolve(downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
  });
  return imageUrl;
};

export const uploadImagesToStorage = async (photos) => {
  const promises = photos.map(async (photo) => {
    const resizedPhoto = await resizePhoto(photo);
    const response = await fetch(resizedPhoto.uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(blob);
    return imageUrl;
  });

  const photoUrls = await Promise.all(promises);

  return photoUrls;
};
```